Modify a segment of a spiral with geometry nodes
I need to deform o modify a segment of a spiral curve with geometry nodes: to turn the last loop into a closed circle. ¿Is it possible?

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

For once, I believe I've understood this question where others have not.. (it's usually the other way round). On this occasion, voting to re-open. If the answer doesn't do what you want, this question definitely needs an edit.

Excuse my persistence, but I'm new here (though not to using Blender). I'm not sure what additional details my question needs. I'm looking for a direct and practical way to convert the last rotation of a spiral into a flat circle (aligned with the Z axis) using Geometry Nodes procedurally. I noticed that one of the group members understood my question perfectly and provided a generous answer, solving a problem that I believe is quite common.

If you've generated the spiral yourself inside GN, you can set the Endpoint Selection of Resolution +1 points to the minimum Z of that selection:

Of course, you could do the same to the other end, taking the maximum Z, instead.


I am immensely grateful; your generous answer has solved a significant problem for me.
